# Run the same test with Nightwatch.js for 100 URLs

Tags: url, testing, nightwatch.js

Is it possible to read a file in Nightwatch where URLs are saved and execute the same test for each of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember nightwatch.js is still javascript, you can read the file of urls (e.g. csv) then iterate through the array of url list.

```
var urls={url1,url2,url3.....url100}
urls.foreach(url){
 browser.url(url);
        .whatever();
}
browser.end();//end only after all urls are finished.
```

Comment: Thanks, thats how I did it yesterday. I posted my answer anyway, but tagged yours as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out yesterday, so I would like to share:

```
module.exports = {

    'Warm-Up Process': function (browser) {

        function urls(url) {
            return browser.launchUrl + url;
        }

        var json = require('./myexport.json');

        json.forEach(function(callurl){
          browser.url(urls(callurl));
          browser.waitForElementVisible('body', 10000);
        });

        browser.end();

    }

};
```

Comment: could u share myexport.json file structure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Is it possible to read a file in Nightwatch where URLs are saved and execute the same test for each of them in a for loop. You'll want to, if possible, ingest it as JSON.

Comment: Personally, I would write a Custom Command, and call that, and have that pull the URLs from where ever they are stored, looping through that with the for loop containing something like .url(url) and followed with a line to confirm that the appropriate URL has loaded. How is the file with the URLs formatted currently? Is that file something you control or are you pulling it from somewhere? Giving more detail - perhaps some code example of your own - to your question will get you a more useful answer. Just loading the url isn't enough, you want to confirm with some pass fail criteria.